# How can I map a 2D array in return statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I store my words inside of an array. I want to change it and store in a 2D array, but I dont know how to make it with this code:

This is my first array using inside of return:

```
words:[
    "Hello",
    "Hi",
    "Where",
    "Which",
    "Who",
    "When",
    "What",
    "Come",
    "Get",
    "Post"
]
```

This is the array which I will create manually and use inside of return instead of first array

```
data: [{
    word: "Hi",
    explain: "Say Hi"
}, {
    word: "Hello",
    explain: "Say Hello"
}]
```

And the first array is returned like this:

````
return this.state.words.map((word, index) => (
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        {word.split("").map((CharacterData, subIndex) => ()```
````

Can anyone guide me on how should i modify the return statement so i can access the all variable inside of the 2D array that i want?

Comment: So you want to convert `["Hello", "Hi"]` to `[{"word": "Hello", explain: "Say Hello"}, {"word": "Hi", explain: "Say Hi"}]`?

Comment: I'm develop a word game and firstly I just do for words but after that I just want to add some explain for hint and I will show it in the view also. So in the first array which is words could not include the explains. This is new feature for my game. And how can I edit the this return method related with this new array type.

Answer (score 1):

ES5:

```js
var words = [
  "Hello",
  "Hi",
  "Where",
  "Which",
  "Who",
  "When",
  "What",
  "Come",
  "Get",
  "Post"
];

var newWords = words.map(function(word) {
  return {
    word: word,
    explain: "Say " + word
  };
});

console.log(newWords);
```

ES6:

```js
var words = [
  "Hello",
  "Hi",
  "Where",
  "Which",
  "Who",
  "When",
  "What",
  "Come",
  "Get",
  "Post"
];

var newWords = words.map(word => ({ word, explain: `Say ${word}` }));

console.log(newWords);
```

React example that prints both properties:

```
var words = [
  "Hello",
  "Hi",
  "Where",
  "Which",
  "Who",
  "When",
  "What",
  "Come",
  "Get",
  "Post"
];

var newWords = words.map(word => ({ word, explain: `Say ${word}` }));

return newWords.map(item => (<View><div>Word: '{item.word}'</div><div>Explain: '{item.explain}'</div></View>))
```

React example that prints all the properties:

```
var words = [
  "Hello",
  "Hi",
  "Where",
  "Which",
  "Who",
  "When",
  "What",
  "Come",
  "Get",
  "Post"
];

var newWords = words.map(word => ({ word, explain: `Say ${word}` }));

return newWords.map(item => (<View>{Object.entries(item).map(group => (<div>{group[0]}: "{group[1]}"</div>))}</View>))
```

Comment: I will create a data array which I said, I just want to know how can I access this elements inside of each object. So, How can I change my return function for able to map and give me for every word and it's explain

Comment: @Atakan Can you please edit your question to include how your final html should look like?

Comment: I'm developing React-Native mobile app so dont have any html

Comment: @Atakan Can you post what the result of the new `return this.state.words.map((word, index) => (
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        {word.split("").map((CharacterData, subIndex) => ()` should look like? It's hard for us to visualize what you want without more info.

Comment: I want exactly that, when I work with "data" array, how should look like my this return function for access the every objects' word and explain

Comment: @Atakan What is `that`? Could you please post a sample input and its respective output? For the record, React-Native still uses HTML, just because you are not writing code for a browser doesn't mean you can use html and js

Comment: I want to access everything inside of that array ```data: [{
    word: "Hi",
    explain: "Say Hi"
}, {
    word: "Hello",
    explain: "Say Hello"
}]```  and then want to map it inside of return func. but how can I change my return function dont know

Comment: @Atakan I updated the answer, is the last part what you are asking for?

Comment: I updated also something, I added up on to your edition lets look

Comment: @Atakan Does either one of the last 2 examples work for you?

Comment: I solve it but could not in here my solutions thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

You can get your data in very simple way

```
    var data=words.map(x=>({"word":x,"explain":`Say ${x}`}))
```

```js
var words=[
      "Hello",
      "Hi",
      "Where",
      "Which",
      "Who",
      "When",
      "What",
      "Come",
      "Get",
      "Post"
    ]
    
var data=words.map(x=>({"word":x,"explain":"Say "+x}))

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to convert `["Hello", "Hi"] to [{"word": "Hello", explain: "Say Hello"}, {"word": "Hi", explain: "Say Hi"}]` You can use the below code to do that.

```
var words = [
  "Hello",
  "Hi",
  "Where",
  "Which",
  "Who",
  "When",
  "What",
  "Come",
  "Get",
  "Post"
]

var newArr = words.map(word => {
    return {word:word,explain:"Say " + word}
})
```

Comment: I dont want to convert it, I will create that array manually and how can I take the each elements' word and explain in the return method. I did it for the first array but new array make me confused for how can I reach the each elements inside of it with that return method.

Comment: @Apoorv why are you creating a new variable named newArr?? Map function already returns an array. please correct your answer

Comment: @VikasSingh You are right .. i have edited my answer